# Android ActionBar in older versions

Tags: android

I want to make android application include the action bar and this app working on versions 2.2 to the latest so as of my understand I have to make the application Android platform 2.1 (level 7) to platform 2.3.4 (level 10) and use the Support library v7 or make the platform 3.0 (level 11) and go on right? So as I want to make the application available from 2.2 to 4.3 with the same features and design which platform to use (2.2 or 4.3) and which one I include the support library and what is the values of (minSDKVersion = 8), maxSDKVersion = 18) and the targetSDKVersion = 18). When I do this the application don't run at all and make an error so I'm confused... I couldn't find a full example of this.
Note: I don't want to work with ActionBarSherlock library and also I got error when I try to extract the zip file downloaded from actionbarsherlock.com

Comment: It seems like you have limited knowledge about android platform versions and want to use the hardest way possible of adding an action bar(not using sherlock). Do you want to avoid Sherlock because of the error when extracting it?

Comment: may be because you are not able to download completely.

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarSherlock is a great library, but with a new project I'd start with ActionBarCompat from a Android Support Library.
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

You need to add android-support-v4 and android-support-v7 to add action bar support on Android.

Comment: I'd actually recommend using ABS over the new ActionBarCompat library.  I've tried both and found ActionBarCompat to have alot more quirks.  ABS is much more mature and seems to work more seemlessly.